# Cargar cadena de conexion desde el App.config

Tags: c#, app.config

Estoy tratando de implementar el uso de una clase conexión con el siguiente código.

```
namespace Datos
{
    public class Conexion
    {

      public static string Cn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conexionBD"].ConnectionString.ToString(); 
    }
}
```

pero de esta manera tiene problemas cuando llamo a **Cn** me arroja error de referencia a una instancia `NULL`

pero si coloco el código de esta manera  si funciona:

```
namespace Datos
{
    public class Conexion
    {    
        public static string Cn = "Data Source=server; Initial Catalog= DbFacturacion; user=sa; password=123456;";
    }
}
```

Agradecido de antemano si alguien me da luces...

Comment: la segunda manera funciona porque no estas recuperando los datos de la configuracion, solo asignas un string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La `cadena de conexion` tomandola de la configuracion no se penso para que la asignes a una variable `static` se supone que debes leerla de la configuracion cuando vayas a trabajar con ese dato o quizas implementarla en el patron singleton

Lo primero que debes validar es que tengas esa key en el `app.config`

[Cadenas de conexión y archivos de configuración](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-strings-and-configuration-files)

```
<connectionStrings>  
  <add name="conexionBD"     
   connectionString="..." />  
</connectionStrings>
```

Entonces defines

```
public class Conexion
{
    public static string GetConnection()
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conexionBD"].ConnectionString;
    }
}
```

Para usarla harias

```
string conn = Conexion.GetConnection();
```

Nota: particularmente no aconsejaria tener una clase de `Conexion` porque lo correcto seria definir una capa de acceso a datos

Comment: public static GetConnection()
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conexionBD"].ConnectionString;
    } de esta manera me arroja un error "No se permiten modificadores de acceso en constructores estáticos"  el metodo debe tener un tipo de valor devuelto

Comment: olvide definirle el tipo de dato de retorno, que seria un string, ahi edite el codigo de ejemplo